# passing complete string value within accordion tab

Tags: php, jquery, textbox, accordion

i have the jquery accordion tabs. within those tabs, i have a hidden form which on click, is auto-filled with certain values displayed within that tab. It displays correctly within the accordion tab but when i pass those same variables as auto-fill values within the form, only the first word gets displayed if there is more than 1 word. the variable name that i have put as the value attribute of the text box is exactly the same so i don't know why this happens.

```
echo "<tr><p><td>".$allCourses[$i][0]."</td> - <td>".$allCourses[$i][1]."</td>
```

it gets displayed correctly here. however, here, only the first word appears:

```
<form action='editCourse.php' method='post'>
<p id='edit-course-d' class='edit-accordion-tab'><img src='images/edit.png' title='Edit Course'/></p>
<p id='edit-course-f' style='display: none'>
Course ID: <input type='text' name='edit-course-id' value =".$allCourses[$i][0]."><br />
Course Name: <input type='text' name='edit-course-name' value=".$allCourses[$i][1]."><br />
```

(all this is within the echo "" in php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put quotes around the content of your `value`-attribute, otherwise the "other words" are interpreted as HTML-attributes. So what is rendered to the browser looks like:

```
<input value=hello world>
```

The browser interprets this as an `input` element which has **two** attributes:

1. `value="hello"`
2. `world=""`

So you have to put quotes `'` or double-quotes `"` around the value of the attribute. Like that:

```
echo "
    <form action='editCourse.php' method='post'>
    <p id='edit-course-d' class='edit-accordion-tab'><img src='images/edit.png' title='Edit Course'/></p>
    <p id='edit-course-f' style='display: none'>
    Course ID: <input type='text' name='edit-course-id' value='".htmlspecialchars($allCourses[$i][0])."'><br />
    Course Name: <input type='text' name='edit-course-name' value='".htmlspecialchars($allCourses[$i][1])."'><br />";
```

I use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape the quotes that might appear inside the values (this adds another layer of safety).